# Plotting horizontal bars with ggplot2 and facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, visualization, data-science

I would like to reproduce this plot, but `ggplot2` it is very slow to finish and the plot return empty at the end.

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfNkQ.png)

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(data = bigram_tf_idf2, aes(x = tf_idf, y = bigram)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip()

g + facet_wrap(~ book, ncol = 2)
```

Sample data set:

```
bigram_tf_idf2 <- data.frame(book = c('Persuasion','Mansfield Park','Mansfield Park','Persuasion','Persuasion','Emma','Northanger Abbey','Sense & Sensibility','Emma','Pride & Prejudice'),
                            bigram = c('captain wentworth','sir thomas','miss crawford','lady russell','sir walter', 'miss woodhouse', 'miss tilney', 'colonel brandon', 'frank churchill', 'lady catherine'),
                            tf_idf = c(0.0535, 0.0515, 0.0386, 0.0371, 0.0356, 0.0305, 0.0286, 0.0269, 0.0248, 0.0247))
```

Comment: welcome to SO. We dont have access to your dataset. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn. Importantly, have you tried looking at similar questions posted on this site? I'm sure there is a question similar to what you've asked somewhere in here. The point here is, posting CODE SNIPPET is NOT ENOUGH. Its imperative to show the Effort to solve the problem.

Comment: You're right! I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = bigram_tf_idf2, aes(x = bigram, y = tf_idf)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip()

p + facet_wrap(~ book, ncol = 2)
```

[image: plot]

Essentially the error in your code was that you had mixed up the x and y axis variable. Remember, on x-axis you plot the categorical variable and the y-axis must be the continuous variable.

**EDIT 1**

To beautify the plot, add `theme()` like,

```
ggplot(data = bigram_tf_idf2, aes(x = bigram, y = tf_idf)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()
```

**EDIT 2**

To add color to the bar's, use `fill`.

```
p <- ggplot(data = bigram_tf_idf2, aes(x = bigram, y = tf_idf,
                                       fill=bigram)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()
p + facet_wrap(~ book, ncol = 2)
```

[image: plot2]

Answer (score 0):

This is the final result and code.

```
bigram_tf_idf %>%
  group_by(book) %>% 
  top_n(12) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(book = as.factor(book),
         bigram = reorder_within(bigram, n, book)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(bigram, tf_idf, fill = book)) + 
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  facet_wrap(~ book, scales = 'free_y', ncol = 2) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(y = 'if_idf de bigramas por livro',
       x = NULL,
       title = 'Analysing Bigrams',
       subtitle = 'Bigrams by Book')
```

[Plot with final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MUkD.png)